# How many WebSites could use same ApplicationPool?

Tags: .net, iis

We have a lot of similar instances of the same websites which are using the same ApplicationPool.

Is it ok? 
Should we change something in ApplicationPool settings?
How many WebSites could use same ApplicationPool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carmelop/archive/2013/03/22/how-many-web-applications-per-application-pool.aspx).It might help you.

Comment: I have a lot of websites on one pool. And sometimes I have trouble with expired Session when it should not be expired.

Is it possible that pool runs out of memory and expires Session? Could this issue be fixed if each WebSite will use different pool?